# Taking the derivative of an expectation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Given the following definition for $J_t$:
\begin{align}
J_t = E_t \int_t^\infty e^{-c (u - t)} \left( a_u^2 + b_u^2 \right) du 
\end{align}
If wollows from Ito's lemma that:
\begin{align}
E_t \left[ \frac{dJ_t}{dt} \right] &= J_{a_t} E_t \left[ \frac{da_t}{dt} \right] + \frac{1}{2} J_{a_t a_t} E_t \left[ \frac{(da_t)^2}{dt} \right] + J_{b_t} E_t \left[ \frac{db_t}{dt} \right] + \frac{1}{2} J_{b_t b_t} E_t \left[ \frac{(db_t)^2}{dt} \right] + J_{a_t b_t} E_t \left[ \frac{da_t db_t}{dt} \right] 
\end{align}
where $a_t$ and $b_t$ behave as follows:
\begin{align}
da_t &= \left[ f_t - b_t + c \right] dt + dZ_t^a \quad \text{given } x_0 \\
\label{eq_a178}
db_t &= \left[ c b_t + k \left( 1 - e^{a_t} \right) \right] dt + dZ_t^b \quad \text{where } \lim_{T \to \infty} E_t [e^{-\delta(T - t)} b_T]=0
\end{align}
Could you help me understand whether:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} E_t \left[ \frac{dJ_t}{dt} \right] \equiv E_t \left[ \frac{d^2J_t}{dt^2} \right]
\end{align}
Is it enough to check the following two conditions?

1. The derivative $dJ_t/dt$  exists and is finite almost surely.
2. The expectation $E[dJ_t/dt]$ is finite for all t.